# SVG fill not coloring the background

Tags: svg

I have an svg and when I define the `fill` it behaves as stroke

For example

```
<svg stroke="black" fill="red">
    <path d="M10 10 H 90 V 90 H 10 Z"/>
</svg>
```

This works as expected, but when I have

```
<svg stroke="black" fill="red">
    <path d="M12,5.41,19.59,13H15v6H9V13H4.41L12,5.41M12,4,3.71,12.29A1,1,0,0,0,4.41,14H8v5a1,1,0,0,0,1,1h6a1,1,0,0,0,1-1V14h3.59a1,1,0,0,0,.71-1.71L12,4Z"/>
</svg>
```

It doesn't. Any suggestions why the fill doesn't work as the other svg ?

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/2zfzLkvg/)

```html
<svg stroke="black" fill="red">
    <path d="M12,5.41,19.59,13H15v6H9V13H4.41L12,5.41M12,4,3.71,12.29A1,1,0,0,0,4.41,14H8v5a1,1,0,0,0,1,1h6a1,1,0,0,0,1-1V14h3.59a1,1,0,0,0,.71-1.71L12,4Z"/>
</svg>

<svg stroke="black" fill="red">
  <path d="M10 10 H 90 V 90 H 10 Z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: The arrow is drawn twice (at slightly different sizes) so there's no real inside to it. The inside (as much as it has an inside) is between the inner and outer arrow shapes, which overlap so it's not obvious there are two shapes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we enlarge the arrow, you will see what is happening.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 40 40"
     stroke="black" fill="red" stroke-width="0.2">
    <path d="M12,5.41,19.59,13H15v6H9V13H4.41L12,5.41M12,4,3.71,12.29A1,1,0,0,0,4.41,14H8v5a1,1,0,0,0,1,1h6a1,1,0,0,0,1-1V14h3.59a1,1,0,0,0,.71-1.71L12,4Z"/>
</svg>
```

As Robert said, you have an arrow shape with an arrow shaped hole inside it.  Your arrow was appearing black, instead of red, because at that small size the thickness of the black stroke was hiding the red fill.

If you want a red arrow with a black outline, then you will need to redesign your shape so that it is just a single outline, not a "double-walled" one.